# Weight Paint Issues...using vertex groups

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups

Trying to apply the appropriate weight paint, however my mesh "breaks" when any form of paint is applied. Am I missing something? I know I have multiple items in on mesh but I'm simply trying to paint a bent shoe...Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance[image]

I've tried automatic weight paint but the results are the same. It seems like every time I decrease the affected area the mesh pixelates and gets distorted in an undesirable manner. I apologize for my ignorance.[image]

Comment: You just need smoother weights.  I would recommend painting it unposed and using the gradient tool.

Comment: Thanks Nathan! I'll try that.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you!!